# How to map dynamic excel rows to sql database columns

Tags: sql, excel, laravel

I am trying to import an excel using Laravel with dynamically changing columns(names as well as sequence) . I am looking for a way to map these columns against Sql db columns.

Answer (score 1):

Please share your code for clarification;

you can use this package to import and change dynamically in callback;

https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel

```
$users = (new FastExcel)->import('file.xlsx', function ($line) {
    //here you can perform custom action on your data
    return User::create([
        'name' => $line['Name'],
        'email' => $line['Email']
    ]);
});
```